# iOS: how to setText for many labels with a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

everyone.
I have 5 labels in my storyboard and I want to set each of its text to be whatever I want. Let's see

```
[cloud0 setText:@"Test0"];
[cloud1 setText:@"Test1"];
[cloud2 setText:@"Test2"];
[cloud3 setText:@"Test3"];
[cloud4 setText:@"Test4"];
```

Now, I use "setText" method for many times as much as number of my label exists.
Is there any method(s) that could be called once, and set each of its text completely the same as mentioned?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Assuming you have an outlet for each label, set it up to use an outlet collection instead. Then you can simply iterate the collection.

Comment: And if your text varies based on position in the collection, you can use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"...format...", vars...]` while you're iterating.

Comment: @rmaddy: my bad ^^" should look at that stuff first, thank you very much btw.

Comment: @BradBrighton I followed your format and it worked well! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set tag to each label with 1 to numberOfLabel(eg. 1 to 5 )

```
-(void)methodSetLabel{
  for(NSInteger i=1;i<=5;i++) {
      UILabel *label=(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
      label.text=[NSString stringWithFormate:@"Test %d",i];
  }
}
```

call this method where u want to set label programmatically

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IBOutletCollection` and set the text by enumerating the collection.

```
[arrayLabelCollection enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UILabel *label, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        label.text = arrayText[idx];
 }];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (UIView *view1 in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([view1 isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            UILabel *lable = (UILabel *) view1;
            lable.text = @"Your Text";
        }
    }
```

try with this